# Geany permission denied

Tags: geany

I wanted to run a small test program, but if I execute it the terminal says:

```
./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: ./main: Permission denied


------------------
(program exited with code: 126)
Press return to continue
```

Comment: Did you make your scripts executable with `chmod +x`?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l`?

Comment: chmod +x and wich directory?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 max max 4096 Nov  1 14:30 Arbeitsfläche
drwxr-xr-x 2 max max 4096 Nov  1 14:30 Bilder
drwxr-xr-x 2 max max 4096 Nov  1 14:30 Dokumente
drwxr-xr-x 2 max max 4096 Nov  2 21:45 Downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1 max max 8445 Okt 30 22:17 examples.desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 max max 4096 Nov  1 14:30 Musik
drwxr-xr-x 2 max max 4096 Nov  1 14:30 Öffentlich
drwxr-xr-x 2 max max 4096 Nov  1 14:30 Videos
drwxr-xr-x 2 max max 4096 Nov  1 14:30 Vorlagen

Comment: I had the same problem as yours.
Note that if you save your program with .c extension and after that, compile, construct and execute, it works fine (for me).

Comment: See how to make file executable from within Geany [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52133967/4414935).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program was stored in a fat system and files's executable bit can't be changed there.

Answer (score 1):

You call in your script another file/script - `./main`. Be sure that you have permission to execute that file (in fact this is saying that exit code: 126). To do this, run the following command:

```
chmod +x /path/to/main
```

Comment: because  i dont call another script its the script itself.

Comment: here the content :http://nopaste.me/paste/444355623527642d42a90f

Comment: @MaxLange The content of what? There is a C program in the given link which can't be executed just like this from terminal.

Answer (score -1):

All I need to to solve Geany permission denied error is to specify the extension of the file that I need to execute in my case I want to execute python programming file e.g. *.py then I save it .py and execute the file by press F5 the permission denied gone.

Comment: Well my file was with `.sh` filename extension and it did not change permission automatically, but see my comment on the question.